# General solution to Wright-Fisher model - Diploid selection

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, mathematical-modeling

Wright-Fisher models are classical theoretical results in evolutionary biology. There are two discrete time models, one for haploid selection and one for diploid selection (the meaning of these models does not matter for the purpose of my question).

My question is: **What is the general solution of the below haploid selection model?**

diploid selection:
$$p(t+1) = p(t)^2 \cdot\frac{W_{AA}}{\bar W} + p(t)q(t)\cdot\frac{W_{Aa}}{\bar W}$$
where $$\bar W = p(t)^2 \cdot W_{AA} + 2p(t)q(t) \cdot W_{Aa} + q(t)^2 \cdot W_{aa}$$

Note that in the above equation $q(t) = 1-p(t)$ by definition

Same question for haploid selection model [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538981/general-solution-to-wright-fisher-model)

---

By general solution, I mean an equation expressing $p(t)$ in function of $p(0)$, $t$, $W_{AA}$, $W_{Aa}$ and $W_{aa}$

$W_{AA}$, $W_{Aa}$ and $W_{aa}$ are different variables. I could have called them $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. One should not try to infer one from another one or anything like this.

$t$ can only take non-negative natural numbers {0,1,2,3,...}

Comment: I'm guessing that $\overline w = \overline W$, correct? Second, there is not enough initial data, for example if $p(t) = f(t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ was given, then a solution can be obtained. Otherwise, with $p(0)$ you can only obtain $p(1), \, p(2), \, \ldots$, and even then I'm quite sure no easily expressible general solution can be found.

Comment: @ArturGower Yes, $\bar w = \bar W$. I fixed this mistake! I did not understand why I am not giving enough initial data. What I am look for is a formula allowing to calculate $p(t)$ for any integer t<0 given that we know $p(t+1) = f(p(t))$ and $p(0)=p_initial$. What data do we miss? Thanks a lot!

Comment: think of it this way, knowing only $p(0)=p_0$, can you figure out $p(0.5)$? The recurrence above only relates $p(t+1)= f(p(t))$, for some $f$. So from $p(0)$ you can find $p(1), \, p(2), \ldots$ but never $p(0.5)$, which you would have to give as initial data, or give the value of $p(-0.5)$, for example.

Comment: @ArturGower The model is a discrete time model and $p$ is only defined for non-negative natural numbers of $t$. Does it make sense? I'm sorry I should have said that. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $p(t+1)=u(p(t))$ where
$$
u(x)=\frac{W_{AA}x^2+W_{Aa}x(1-x)}{W_{AA}x^2+2W_{Aa}x(1-x)+W_{aa}^2(1-x)^2}.
$$
There exists no formula for the iteration of $u$ in the generic case. The asymptotics of $p(t)$, on the other hand, are easier to describe, using a phase diagram on $[0,1]$.